# Can I unlock all the specializations from the start of the game?

Tags: pc, dragon-age-origins

Is there a way (cheat and/or mod, savegame) to unlock all specializations in the first game run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a mod for that, that will unlock all specializations](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=316). The specializations are unlocked for all playthroughs, once you unlock them.